# How do i use select with if and else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have made fiddle and put it below. i have a select option, with 2 options owner and non-owner. then based on what is picked questions are asked. i add you the answer and give back feedback. my trouble is i am trying to use a if statement to say if they are owner or not-owner and i am not sure what i should use to say if select = owner.

```
<div class="list owner">
Number 1: <input id="box1" type="text" /><br/>
Number 2: <input id="box2" type="text" /><br/>
Number 3: <input id="box3" type="text" /><br/>
</div>

<div class="list not-owner">

Number 4: <input id="box1" type="text" /><br/>
Number 5: <input id="box2" type="text" /><br/>
Number 6: <input id="box3" type="text" /><br/>
</div>
<button id="butt">Go</button>
<div id="output">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/philyphil/CcVsz/11/embedded/result/

Comment: Your option elements should use `value="..."` rather than `data-val="..."`, and then you can test whether the current selection is "owner" with `if ($('.myOptions').val() === "owner") { /* do something */ }`. By the way, since you are asking about the select element it would be helpful to include the select html and associated JavaScript in your question, rather than showing all those inputs that really having nothing to do with what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry put it in the fiddle to keep it short. http://jsfiddle.net/philyphil/CcVsz/13/embedded/result/

Comment: Yes, I obviously saw the original fiddle given that I gave you feedback about stuff in the fiddle not shown in the question. My point is the extract you actually showed in the question has nothing to do with what you're asking about - if you're going to show just part of your code show the relevant part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

change your select to this

```
<select id="typeselect" class="myOptions">
  <option data-val="" selected="">Pick an option</option>
  <option data-val="owner">Owner</option>
  <option data-val="not-owner">Not Owner</option>
</select>
```

then the javasceipt should be

```
var e = document.getElementById("typeselect");
    var ev = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

then

```
if(ev==='Owner'){
//code goes here
}
else{
//code goes here
}
```

dont forget to use three equal signs ====

Comment: i did didn't work for me   http://jsfiddle.net/philyphil/CcVsz/13/embedded/result/

Comment: where is your javascript in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @SubhashSasidharakurup - OP is linking to the fiddle "result"; just click "Edit in JSFiddle" to see the markup and JS.

Comment: @Subhash the imputes are not being added just saying owner...but the if is working and from that i should be able to make it work how i want it...will try now and let you know....thank you!....thanks a million to everyone else as well!!!

Comment: @@SubhashSasidharakurup or anyone else please. This working how i want for half of it. if i pick my first option owner it does what i want, user puts in a number 1-10 each has it's own value and it adds the 3 inputs, my problem is if i pick non-owner. then it is not getting input...i don't understand because either option picked is still going to the same input? box1,box2,box,3...if someone could get this to work for me, i would realy appreciate it.

http://jsfiddle.net/philyphil/CcVsz/32/

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML code as

```
<select class="myOptions">
  <option value="" selected>Pick an option</option>
  <option value="owner">Owner</option>
  <option value="not-owner">Not Owner</option>
</select>
```

To get value use

```
$('.myOptions').val();
```

Using this, frame your `if..else..` statement.

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/CcVsz/12/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function f(a)
{
if(a=="owner")
{
do something
}
}
</script>

<select onchange=f(this.value)>
<option >Pick an option</option>
<option >Owner</option>
<option >Not Owner</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you used semantically correct data attributes, to get the value from the selected option with your current html, you would use

```
var opt = $('.myoptions').find('option:selected').data('val');
```

and your test would then be

```
if ( opt == 'owner' ) {
}
```

I'm fairly sure you can shorten this to

```
var opt = $('.myoptions option:selected').data('val');
```

This will look strange to anyone not familiar with html 5 custom data attributes however, so you may consider using the more familiar

```
<option value="owner">Owner</option>
```

and testing and using

```
var opt = $('myoptions').val();
```

Comment: _"This will look strange to anyone not familiar with html 5 custom data attributes..."_ - It will also look strange to people who _are_ familiar with them, because using `data-val` instead of `value` is just weird for option elements. (But yes, that should work for the OP's markup.)

Comment: i tried with both of your opt's the if ,is still not catching http://jsfiddle.net/philyphil/CcVsz/14/

Comment: It's sort of incorrect: it'd need to be `value` if the select element were to be included in a form submission. You already suggested the "right" way at the end of your answer; I'd suggest it is "right" even if no form submission will ever occur in this case, because unnecessary use of unusual techniques just makes the code harder to understand and maintain even if it does work.

Comment: @Philly - That latest fiddle changed the html to use `value=` but then used JS that expected `data-val=`. Also, you're running the if test outside of your event handlers, so it will run immediately on load.

Comment: nnnnnn: you caught me. I was being nice to the poster. Philly: as you have it now, the code will run on page load. You want to run it as an event response

Comment: lol unnecessary use of unusual techniques sound about right! lol total new... been doing a lot of reading but not using it, now trying to use it and not going to good. got a lot more to do! i was trying to make it run if they click go.

Comment: Dom: nice is nice, don't let me talk you out of being nice. Philly, sorry, please take my comments as constructive criticism - which _is_ how I meant them (not as destructive ha-ha-look-at-the-newbie-mistakes criticism).

Comment: @nnnnn can you show me what you mean in a fiddle.. going crazy with this for days, i cant find anywhere to look at and go by. I usually need a base to go by then i can figure it out. I can not ask no more questions...wish i knew we where so strict here. Warned me i had one more bad question or something! I can't help myself stuck trying to make this work..once i get it working i can go back to some much need reading

Comment: The second part of Dom's answer already does what I was talking about. That is, use `value="owner"` in your option element (and similar for your other options), and then `$('.myoptions').val()` to get the value of the currently selected option.